# How to access images directly from Google Cloud Storage (GCS) when using Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have developed a model in Keras that works perfectly when reading data stored locally.  However, I now want to take advantage of Google Cloud Platform's GPUs for training the model.  I have set up the GPU on GCP and am working in a Jupyter notebook.  I have moved my images to Google Cloud Storage.

My question is:

**How can I access these images (specifically the directories -  training, validation, test) directly from Cloud Storage using the Keras' flow_from_directory method of the [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) class?**

here's my directory structure in Google Cloud Storage (GCS):

```
mybucketname/
      class_1/
          img001.jpg
          img002.jpg
          ...
      class_2/
          img001.jpg
          img002.jpg
          ...
      class_3/
          img001.jpg 
          img002.jpg
          ...
```

Comment: I've found that copying the files directly from Cloud Storage to the VM works via `import os, sys
os.system('gsutil cp -r gs://mybucketname/ .')` but that's not the elegant solution I was hoping for...

Comment: You will need your own custom generator.

Comment: Looks like copying from bucket to vm is the only way. gsutil is the most practical way, the client api would be several lines of code extra.

Answer (score 4):

While I haven't yet figured out a way to read the image data directly from GCS, in the meantime I can copy the files directly from Cloud Storage to the VM via `import os, sys os.system('gsutil cp -r gs://mybucketname/ .')`

Comment: thank you for sharing this solution! Do you know if in the meanwhile anything appeared that allows to load the files *directly* from the bucket to directory in `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(
    directory, ...)` ? I have tried putting in the `gs://mybucketname/` but that does not work.